# RFID project using STM32F446 Nucleo board, I need to feed my board with 5 V using a powerbank, is that possible?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, power-electronics, rfid

I'm working on an RFID project using an STM32F446 Nucleo board. I need to feed my board with 5 V using a powerbank, is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work.

Comment: Of course it is possible. But it depends where you connect 5V and how. We don't know that.

Comment: If the board wants 5 V, then yes, if you connect things properly. Note that most power banks switch off after a pre-set time when insufficient current is pulled from them. This could be a problem depending on how much current your circuit wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply it from external 5V source:

[image]

[image]

Image source: [STM32 Nucleo-64 boards (MB1136) User manual UM1724](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf)